# React Native Network Image Doesn't Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The code I am writing is for wordpress.

I have succeed in fetching titles, category IDs and featured media IDs. Then I try to fetch the image uri to display it.

The wired thing is: Every time the post title and category id and author id come very fast, however, the image doesn't show until I press load more (which is built in by Gifted Listview). The requests happen both at "load more" and "ListViewOnFresh", so it should be like this.

I tried to use console.log to output "start loading" and "loading finished" when image starts and ends ending. However, I can see it was never loaded unless I press load more.

Even if it is loaded, if I pull to refresh (call the ListViewOnRefresh), it will disappear again.

I tried also to output dataRows, it has no problem at all, the featured_image is showing the right uri.

I really cannot solve this. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
var MovieListScreen = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        Controllers.NavigationControllerIOS("movies_nav").setLeftButtons([{
            title: "Categories",
            onPress: function() {
                Controllers.DrawerControllerIOS("drawer").toggle({side:"left"});
            }
        }]);
    },



    renderListViewRow: function(row){
        return(
            <View >
                <TouchableHighlight underlayColor={'#f3f3f2'} onPress={()=>this.selectRow(row)}>
                    <View style={styles.articleContainer}>
                        <View style={styles.rowDetailsContainer}>
                            <Image resizeMode="cover" style={styles.featuredImage}
                                source={{uri: row.featured_image}}
                                 onLoadStart={() =>{console.log('start loading')}}
                                onLoadEnd={() => {console.log('loading finished')}}
                                />
                            <Text style={styles.articleTitle}>
                                    {row.title.rendered}
                                </Text>
                                <Text style={styles.articleTime} >
                                    Posted by {row.author}, Category: {row.categories[0]}
                                </Text>
                                <Text style={styles.articleExcerpt}>
                                    {row.excerpt.rendered}
                                </Text>

                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                    <View style={styles.separator}/>
                    <View style={styles.articleActions}>
                        <Icon style={{flex:1}} name="share-alt" size={20} color="#0088CC" />
                        <Icon style={{flex:1}} name="thumbs-o-up" size={20} color="#0088CC" />
                        <Icon style={{flex:1}} name="star-o" size={20} color="#0088CC" />
                        <View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}><Icon style={{flex:1}} name="external-link" size={20} color="#0088CC" /><Text style={{fontSize:15,color:'#0088CC'}}> Read More</Text></View>



                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        },
        listViewOnRefresh: function(page, callback){
            var rowsData = [];
            var REQUEST_URL = 'http://jo.wtf/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10&order=asc&page='+page;

            fetch(REQUEST_URL)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {responseData.map((obj)=>{
                fetch('http://jo.wtf/wp-json/wp/v2/media/'+obj.featured_media)
                .then((responseMedia) => responseMedia.json())
                .then((responseDataMedia) => {
                    obj.featured_image= responseDataMedia.guid.rendered;
                })
                rowsData.push(obj);
                console.log(rowsData);
            })
            callback(rowsData);
            return;
        })
        .done();
    },

    selectRow: function(row){
        var navigationController = Controllers.NavigationControllerIOS("movies_nav");
        navigationController.push({
            component: "PushedScreen", // the unique ID registered with AppRegistry.registerComponent (required)
            backButtonTitle: "", // override the nav bar back button title for the pushed screen (optional)
            backButtonHidden: false, // hide the nav bar back button for the pushed screen altogether (optional)
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <RefreshableListView renderRow={(row)=>this.renderListViewRow(row)}
                onRefresh={(page, callback)=>this.listViewOnRefresh(page, callback)}
                backgroundColor={'#EFEFEF'}
                style={styles.listview}/>
        );
    },

});
```

Comment: Full code publish to Github https://github.com/JO-WTF/React-Native-Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add 
style={{width:200,height:300}} 
to your Image tag

Comment: Thanks. I think it is just because I am making 2 API calls. I have changed the wordpress code to output all what I want in a single API call. The problem is thus solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem in another way.

I tried to rewrite the code with async functions but it didn't help either. I think it is caused by 2 api calls at the same time, although why I cannot do that.

Anyway, I don't want to call one API to fetch the thumbnail ID and then call N APIs to get the url for those thumbnails, so I changed the wordpress API.

Add some code to the function.php file into my theme solved it.

It seems I cannot insert php code here... See here:
http://jo.wtf/adding-extra-fields-to-wp-api-output/